# Issue bringing up Hyperledger Fabric "Building Your First Network" sample

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

while I am running this command from my terminal

```
sudo ./byfn.sh  -m up
```

I am getting below error:

> Starting with channel 'my-channel' and CLI    timeout of '10' seconds
>   and CLI delay of '3' seconds Continue (y/n)?    y proceeding ...
>   Pulling orderer.example.com    (hyper-ledger/fabric-orderer:latest)...
>   ERROR: manifest for    hyper-ledger/fabric-orderer:latest not found
>   ERROR !!!! Unable to    start network Error response from daemon: No
>   such container: cli

How do I resolve this please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download platform specific binaries, please see how to do it here in the following [tutorial](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/samples.html). Please also make sure you have all per-requisites, you can find more about what needed [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/prereqs.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should download the platform binaries and images as given in the Fabric documentation - [Install Binaries and Docker Images](https://web.archive.org/web/20211207185129/https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/getting_started.html#install-binaries-and-docker-images)
**Or**
You should make sure that your terminal has internet access & not behind any corporate proxy. Whatever is needed would be pulled by docker anyway. I am guessing that ***hyperledger/fabric-baseos*** image is not pulled by the script above.

If you don't find **hyperledger/fabric-baseos:latest**,then either docker pull hyperledger/fabric-baseos:***tag depends on the fabric version*** on your own

Or, the chaincode instantiate process in byfn- end to end CLI would do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out it was just a broken docker-compose installation. I simply figured it out typing `docker-compose` in my terminal, and I ran into `ImportError: No module named ssl_match_hostname`
With a clean docker compose install, I got it to work.